# GRASS: import PostGIS vector layer into SQLite database

Tags: grass-gis, sqlite

I am working with vector layers (points) composed of more than 100 000 geometries. These layers are originally in a PostGis database and I import them with `v.in.ogr`, using a formulation like:

```
v.in.ogr \
    input="PG:host=127.0.0.1 dbname=gisdb user=user password=secret" \
    layer=schema.points \
    output=points \
    -o --overwrite
```

This command is successful, however, operations with the resulting `points` layer are remarkably slow. For instance, this layer must be later loaded in R and that operation alone is taking over 3 hours.

After some back-and-forth testing, I identified the problem: `v.in.ogr` is not saving its output in the internal GRASS SQLite database. Knowing this, I can create a copy of the original output, that is automatically inserted into the SQLite database, e.g.:

`g.copy vector=points,points_mirror`

Importing the `points_mirror` layer to R takes 3 minutes instead of 3 hours, for instance.

While mirroring vectors imported with `v.in.ogr` solves the issue, it is an inelegant solution that also takes up unnecessary space. I would prefer to instruct `v.in.ogr` somehow to force it to use the SQLite database. I could not find any reference in the manual, is it possible to do?

Comment: Let me recommend to discuss this on grass-dev (https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/)