# GRASS: db.in.ogr fails where v.in.ogr succeeds

Tags: grass-gis

This is a follow up on a previous question on [the storage of vectors layers imported from PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316100/grass-import-postgis-vector-layer-into-sqlite-database).

To importing a spatial table from PostGIS I use, sucessfully, the following formulation with `v.in.ogr`:

```
> v.in.ogr input="PG:host=pg-server dbname=dsm user=duque004 password=secret" layer="observations.profiles" output=profiles -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <observations.profiles> contains polygons...
ERROR 1: Could not fetch SRS: 
 100%
Creating attribute table for layer <observations.profiles>...
Importing 141584 features (OGR layer <observations.profiles>)...
 100%
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <profiles@test>...
Registering primitives...
```

But if I feed the same parameters to `db.in.ogr`, it fails to find the table:

```
> db.in.ogr input="PG:host=pg-server dbname=dsm user=duque004 password=secret" db_table="observations.profiles" output=profiles
ERROR: Unable to open data source <observations.profiles>
ERROR: Input table <observations.profiles> not found or not
       readable
```

What is going on here?

**Edit**: these outputs report to GRASS 7.6.0

**Update 01-05-2019**: This issue is now reported in [ticket 3836](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3836#ticket).

Comment: in your PG: portion, can you try to add `schemas=observations` and then just use `db_table=profiles`

Comment: Please tell us which GRASS GIS version you use

Comment: @SaultDon `schemas` is not a valid parameter; neither is `schema`.

Comment: @markusN I am working with GRASS 7.6.0, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hit by a SQL restriction:

*No dots are allowed as SQL does not support '.' (dots) in table names.*

See also the related help text at:

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/sql.html#database-table-name-restrictions

Comment: `observations` is the name of the schema where the table resides; the name of the table in question is simply `profiles`. As far asI know, there is no other way to pass the database schema in the connection string. In Postgres and Oracle every table must be in a schema, this dot might not be avoidable.

Comment: I'd suggest to open a ticket at https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ to get this clarified.